How to change camera direction in babylonJS?
I have a and array of cameras streaming videos.
i need half of them to use useRightHandedSystem, and the other half to use useLeftHandedSystem.
But when I do Scene.useRightHandedSystem = false, it changes the whole thing.
Can i make this conditionally, based on camera name?
// Makes 6 small canvas, and inserts camera with streaming for each canvas
 multipleCanvasCreation(scene) {
      for (const cameraInformation of this.cameraInformations) {
        const canvas = document.getElementById(`${cameraInformationrmation.name}_myCanvas`);

        // Set handedness for the camera
        if (
          cameraInformation.name === "cam1" ||
          cameraInformation.name === "cam3" ||
          cameraInformation.name === "cam5"
        ) {
          const camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera(
            `${cameraInformation.name}_eachcamera`,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            cameraInformation._p.add(cameraInformation._dir.scale(this.deltaTarget)),
            scene
          );

          camera.fov = (this.lastfov * Math.PI) / 180;
          camera.maxZ = this.far;
          camera.minZ = this.near;
          this.engine.registerView(canvas, camera);
          cameraInformation._eachCamera = camera;
        } else if (
          cameraInformation.name === "cam2" ||
          cameraInformation.name === "cam4" ||
          cameraInformation.name === "cam6"
        ) {
          const camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera(
            `${cameraInformation.name}_eachcamera`,
            0,
            0,
            1,
            cameraInformation._p.add(cameraInformation._dir.scale(this.deltaTarget)),
            scene
          );

          camera.fov = (this.lastfov * Math.PI) / 180;
          camera.maxZ = this.far;
          camera.minZ = this.near;

          camera.setPosition(cameraInformation._p.clone());

          this.engine.registerView(canvas, camera);

          cameraInformation._eachCamera = camera;
        }
      }
    }

The above is currently working fine, but i just want to change the handedSystem based on camera name, not globally.
useRightHandedSystem is set to false in initialization.
